# Maven dependency graph missing in NetBeans 6.9

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans

NetBeans had a really cool feature that would allow you to view all of a Maven project's dependencies as a graph. Well, I recently upgraded from 6.8 to 6.9, and while all the other Maven stuff works fine, the menu item for the dependency graph has vanished. I couldn't find any information on the NetBeans site. Does anybody know if this feature was removed? Or am I just missing some configuration option?

Comment: may be it resolved at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123620/netbeans-7-dependency-graph-unused-class-method/12910285#12910285

Jirka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Creating an Enterprise Application Using Maven](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp.html) (applies to NetBeans 6.9), the dependency graph is supposed to be available:

> You can right-click in `pom.xml` and
>   choose Show Dependency Graph to see a
>   visual representation of the project
>   dependencies. You can place your
>   cursor over an artifact to display a
>   tooltip with the artifact details.
>
> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [netbeans.org](http://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/68/javaee/mavenentapp/maven-webpomgraph.png))</sub>

I can't confirm this as I'm not using NetBeans 6.9 right now but I doubt they removed this nice feature.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I used to right-click on the "Libraries" tab, and select it from that menu. Looks like they just re-organized the menus.

Comment: I am using netbeans 6.9.1 and there you can also directly right-click on the project name and choose "Show Dependency Graph".

Comment: That's a very nice feature.  Can it also be used for Java SE projects?

Answer (score 11):

For those using NetBeans 7.2, you now have to open the pom.xml, right click on its tab and select "Editors > Graph".