# NetBeans 7 dependency graph (unused class/method)

Tags: class, graph, maven, dependencies, netbeans-7

Is there a way to create a dependency graph for classes and/or methods of Java SE projects within NetBeans 7?  I have a very large project and I'd like to clean up unused classes or methods (and a dependency graph would also be useful).

The "center" of the graph would be the `main()` entry point of main classes I invoke, and adjacencies would be method calls (including some Swing framework methods to classes which override the Java Swing framework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's weird, when I right click on a project in NetBeans 7.0.1 I can choose "Show dependency graph" and it shows me a dependency graph, complete with conflicts and everything!

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I was able to search Google for "Show dependency graph" and the top result was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213689/maven-dependency-graph-missing-in-netbeans-6-9.  I don't know how to set up my project with Maven (perhaps it needs to be a Java EE project?) but I'll do some more research.

Answer (score 2):

if you want method dependency (calll hirearchy) viewer, it is descripted:
http://netbeans.dzone.com/announcements/new-class-visualization-module

in plugin manager add update center:
    http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/dev/uc/final/main/catalog.xml.gz
and
http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

now you can install

## Graphical Class View

Version: 1.4 Source: Latest Development Build
Plugin Description
Provides a diagram of Java classes showing interdependencies between fields and methods in that class. Useful for quickly figuring out what are the important methods and fields in an unfamiliar Java class.

you can invoke right click to method -> graphical view,

is it ? Jirka

Comment: Thanks.  The description link isn't up right now but I found an archived copy of it: http://web.archive.org/web/20100105175804/http://netbeans.dzone.com/announcements/new-class-visualization-module

I'll try it out as soon as I get a chance.